# Get path of upload multiple files

Tags: javascript

I have a file upload button, and I want to get the path of selected file.
Here's my code:

```js
var pniotApp = angular.module('pniotApp', []);
pniotApp.controller('pniotCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location) { 
    var temp = [];
    Array.prototype.push.apply(temp, element.files);
    for (i = 0; i < temp.length;i++)
        $scope.fileBuffer.push(temp[i])
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body dir="rtl" ng-app="pniotApp" ng-controller="pniotCtrl">
  <input id="uploadFile" type="file" class="filestyle" data-classButton="btn btn-primary"  multiple        data-input="false"  data-classIcon="icon-plus"    onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileSelected(this)" data-buttonText="uplaod...">
 
</body>
```

Note: I'm using 'temp' because element.files doesn't behave like an normal array.

How can I get the relative path of the files?
I tried to do this

```
document.getElementById("uploadFile").value
```

But I get just the path of the first file.
What can I do?

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav.
For security reasons browsers do not disclose file path

Answer (score 0):

[You can't access the path for security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav) but since you are satisfied with `.value` for a single entry, I will assume you mean the file *name*.

A file input will have a `files` property that contains a list of the selected files (you can loop over it like an array). The objects inside each have a `name` property that will give you the file name.

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("change", list_files);

function list_files() {
  var files = this.files;
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    console.log(files[i].name);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple>
```

Comment: I need to get the path and document.getElementById("uploadFile").value give me the loction of the file.

Comment: `document.getElementById("uploadFile").value` typically gives you something like `c:\fakepath\the-actual-name`. As the linked question says, you can't get the full path.

Comment: yes, I see, can i get something like c:\fakepath\the-actual-name for all the files?

Comment: ```c:\fakepath\``` is utter nonsense. It is made up junk designed to look like a full path while leaking no information about how the user organises their files. So you can take the name (as per the code in this answer) and put your own utter nonsense at the front of it. `console.log("C:\\fakepath\\" + files[i].name);`